# How do I get a React Native TextInput to maintain focus after submit?

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I could explain what I am trying to do, but [this ReactJS example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) is a walkthrough of exactly what I want. The problem is I can't figure out what the equivelant would be for react native.

Basically, when I press return in the TextInput, I want the text cleared and focus maintained.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've submitted a PR with a `blurOnSubmit` property.

Set it to `false` and the `TextInput` never blurs, `onSubmitEditing` still fires though.

Hopefully it gets merged. :)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/2149

Answer (score 6):

I came out with following (working) solution:

```
var NameInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      textValue: ''
    }
  },

  clearAndRetainFocus: function(evt, elem) {
    this.setState({textValue: elem.text});
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.setState({textValue: this.getInitialState().textValue});
      this.refs.Name.focus();
    }.bind(this), 0);
  },

  render() {
    return(
      <TextInput
        ref='Name'
        value={this.state.textValue}
        onEndEditing={this.clearAndRetainFocus} />
    )
  }
});
```

So, basically when we end editing, we will set the `textValue` state to the value of the `TextInput` and right after that (in `setTimeout`), we switch it back to default (empty) and retain focus on the element.

Comment: This only works half the time. Increasing the timeout helps, but there has to be a solution that will always work.

Comment: It is more reliable with the software keyboard, but the keyboard jumps closed then open.

Comment: What about doing it on `onSubmitEditing`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to trigger blurOnSubmit but if you do and it works you should do that. Another thing I found that works with a functional react component in a chat application i am making is this:

```
... import statments

const ChatInput = props => {
const textIn = React.useRef(null) //declare ref
useEffect(()=>textIn.current.focus()) //use effect to focus after it is updated

const textInputChanged = (text) =>{
    props.contentChanged(text);
}

const submitChat = () =>{
    const txt = props.content.trim()
    txt.length >0 ?  props.sendChat(txt, props.username) : null;
}

const keyPressEvent = (e) =>{
   return e.key == 'Enter'? submitChat() : null;
}

return (
     
        <TextInput 
        style={styles.textInput}
        keyboardType={props.keyboardType}
        autoCapitalize={props.autoCapitalize}
        autoCorrect={props.autoCorrect}
        secureTextEntry={props.secureTextEntry}
        value={props.content}
        onChangeText={textInputChanged}  
        onKeyPress={keyPressEvent}
        autoFocus={true}  //i don't think you need this since we are using useEffect
        ref={textIn} //make it so this is the ref
    />
   )}
... export default react-redux connect stuff
```

if you have more inputs you can probably do some sort of ref choosing logic in the useEffect hook

this is the article that helped me figure it out, it's almost the same thing:
https://howtocreateapps.com/how-to-set-focus-on-an-input-element-in-react-using-hooks/